# CSS: Height of span and li won't match

Tags: html, css, styles, padding

http://goldencraft.co/stackoverflow-test/

HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
<li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
<li>item 2
<ul class="list">
<li>item 2 -> sub item 1 <a href="#" class="button orange"><span>Stack Overflow</span></a></li>
<li>item 2 -> sub item 2
<ul class="list">
<li>sub item 2 -> sub-sub item 1</li>
<li>sub item 2 -> sub-sub item 2</li>
</ul></li>
<li>item 2 -> sub item 3
</ul></li>
<li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.list li {
    padding-left: 12px;
    line-height: 2em;
    background: url('../images/list_arrow.png') no-repeat 0px 8px;
}
ol ol,
ol ul,
ul ol,
ul ul {
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

I cannot figure out the following:

1. Make the `line-height` and/or `padding` match up with the button css style ([click here to view](http://goldencraft.co/wp-content/themes/minecraft/assets/styles/button.css) [see `.button span`])
2. Align the (background-image) arrow to the line of text (if 1 gets fixed, this is easy to do with simple `background-position`)

I'm hoping someone here has a solution, as I'd love to finish this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you might be looking for something like the following:

```
a.button, a.button:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;

    margin-top:-0.1em;
    height:1.4em;
    top:0.5em;
}

button span
{
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    /*border-top: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 1px solid;*/
    line-height: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0px !important;

    padding: 0 0.75em;
    top:-0.3em;
}
```

Comment: I just tried your code, it fixed the height issue but made the button smaller, think you could make it so the button doesn't shrink?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was what you wanted. How about just keeping all the original CSS and just setting 'a.button' 'margin-top:-0.1em;'?